# Zoom controls on emulator running Android 1.6 with QVGA

Tags: android, emulation, fragmentation

I'm testing my app on different AVD setups in the emulator and ran into problems with zoom controls in MapView on Android 1.6 using QVGA resolution only (lcd.density=120).

When tapping on the screen so the zoom controls are displayed, the zoom in/plus sign is displayed much larger than zoom out, which seem to have the correct resolution.

I've tested different combination of Android versions and resolutions but only 1.6 with QVGA resolution seem to be having this issue. I've searched on Google but only found two Tattoo user reporting the same problems on their phones that seem to use QVGA.

Is this a known issue with the emulator only or is it still an issue on real phones? Why I want to support 1.6 is because SE X10-Mini has gained huge success here in Sweden and this phone run exactly 1.6 with QVGA until SE finally upgrade the phone.