# Android: Why is the zoom control like this?

Tags: android, maps, zooming

[image]

Why does the zoom control show like this? It only happens on QVGA resolution smulator. It works perfectly on HVGA resolution.

This is the code that I used.

```
    ZoomControls zoomControls = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomcontrols);
    zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                mc.zoomIn();
        }
    });
    zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                mc.zoomOut();
        }
    });
```

`zoomcontrols` defined in xml as:

```
<ZoomControls android:id="@+id/zoomcontrols"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be nothing wrong with your code. It could be a emulator bug. You should test it on a real device if you can.

It seems you are not the only one. [Zoom controls on emulator running Android 1.6 with QVGA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811956)